# Passing a command to command line programm in a batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

By hand I use a command line (Java) program.

1) I start the program like this

```
Program.bat
```

2) Then the program is started and I can enter commands like this:

```
> COMMAND
```

But when I write batch file like this

```
program.bat
COMMAND
```

Then the command is not passed to the Command Line Program. The command is executed after the program is closed. So when I enter the command 'help' I get the help output of CMD and not of the program. The is probably because the program redirects the stream. Is it possible to execute the command like I do this by hand?

Comment: Just to add the following did not work "java.exe com.program %*" did not work.

Comment: Try `echo help | Program.BAT` or `echo COMMAND | Program.BAT`

Answer (score 2):

You have a couple of options...

Either send the commands to `Program.BAT` using an `echo` command like this:

```
echo HELP | Program.BAT

echo COMMAND | Program.BAT
```

Or, create a separate file of the commands you want the program to run, let's say you create file called `COMMANDS.TXT` that contains these two commands that your program understands:

```
 COMMAND1
 COMMAND2
```

Then submit that to your program using this syntax:

```
 Program.BAT < COMMANDS.TXT
```

Comment: Thnx, I tried the syntax "Program.BAT < COMMANDS", but forgot that I must be in file.